# Why does this Y Combinator using code fail to compile?

Tags: c++, lambda, y-combinator

I've been reading about combinators for three days now and I finally started writing them in code (more like copying stuff from places and making sense of things).

Here's some code that I'm trying to run:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Lambda>
class y_combinator {
  private:
    Lambda lambda;
  public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr explicit y_combinator (T&& lambda)
        : lambda (std::forward <T> (lambda))
    { }

    template <typename...Args>
    decltype(auto) operator () (Args&&... args) {
        return lambda((decltype(*this)&)(*this), std::forward <Args> (args)...);
    }
};

template <typename Lambda>
decltype(auto) y_combine (Lambda&& lambda) {
    return y_combinator <std::decay_t <Lambda>> (std::forward <Lambda> (lambda));
}

int main () {
    auto factorial = y_combine([&] (auto self, int64_t n) {
        return n == 1 ? (int64_t)1 : n * self(n - 1);
    });
    
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << factorial(n) << '\n';
}
```

If I explicitly state the return type of the lambda as `-> int64_t`, everything works well. However, when I remove it, the compiler complains. The error:

```
main.cpp|16|error: use of 'main()::<lambda(auto:11, int64_t)> [with auto:11 = y_combinator<main()::<lambda(auto:11, int64_t)> >; int64_t = long long int]' before deduction of 'auto'
```

Why can't the compiler figure out the return type and deduce auto? I first thought that maybe I needed to change `... ? 1 : n * self(n - 1)` to `... ? int64_t(1) : n * self(n - 1)` so that the type of both return values ends up as `int64_t` and no possible ambiguities remain. This doesn't seem to be the case though. What am I missing?

Also, in the `y_combinator` class, declaring `lambda` as an object of type `Lambda&&` seems to cause problems. Why is this the case? This only happens when I write the cast in the `operator ()` overload as `(decltype(*this)&)` instead of `std::ref(*this)`. Are they doing different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Type deduction

The type of `n == 1 ? (int64_t)1 : n * self(n - 1)` depends on the the return type of `self`, therefore it can't be deduced.  You would think that `int64_t` is an obvious candidate, but `float` and `double` are also just as good.  You can't expect the compiler to consider every possible return type and choose the best candidate.

To fix this instead of using a ternary expression, use an if-else block:

```
int main () {
    auto factorial = y_combine([&] (auto self, int64_t n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return (int64_t)1;
        } else {
            return n * self(n - 1);
        }
    });
    // ...
}
```

With this one of the return statements doesn't depend on the return type of `self`, so type deduction can happen.

When deducting the return type of a function, the compiler looks at all of the return statements in the body of the function *in sequence* and tries to deduce their type.  If it fails you get a compilation error.

Using the ternary operator the type of the return statement `return n == 1 ? (int64_t)1 : n * self(n - 1);` depends on the return type of `self`, which is not yet known.  Therefore you get a compilation error.

When using an if statement and multiple return statements, the compiler can deduce the return type from the first one it encounters, since

> If there are multiple return statements, they must all deduce to the same type.

and

> Once a return statement has been seen in a function, the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function, including in other return statements.

as seen on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction).  This is why

```
        if (n == 1) {
            return (int64_t)1;
        } else {
            return n * self(n - 1);
        }
```

can be deduced to return an `int64_t`.

As a side note

```
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1; // no explicit cast to int64_t
        } else {
            return n * self(n - 1);
        }
```

would fail to compile because from the first return statement the return type of the function will be deduced as `int`, and from the second return statement as `int64_t`.

```
        if (n != 1) {
            return n * self(n - 1);
        } else {
            return (int64_t)1;
        }
```

would also fail, because the first return statement it incounters depends on the  return type of the function, so it can't be deduced.

## Second question

The error happens because when calling `lambda` you're trying to make a copy of `*this` because of the lambda's `auto self` parameter.  This is due to having an rvalue reference member. (see clang's great error message on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YdWrrf))

To fix this either use `std::ref` as mention in the original question or make the lambda have an `auto &&self` parameter (and use `std::forward<decltype(self)>(self)`).

Also note that the member `Lambda &&lambda` is an rvalue reference, so you can only construct an instance of `y_combinator` with a temporary or moved lambda.  In general copying functors in not a big deal, the standard library also takes functor parameters by copy.

Comment: Could also just use an explicit return type, `[](auto self, int64_t n) -> int64_t { ... }`

Comment: @N.Shead True, but that was already mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what difference there is between `if` and `?:` for type deduction.

Comment: Same as Kostas, I'm not sure I completely  understand the "why". I would mark the answer as accepted because maybe there are differences in the working of type deduction for `if` and `?:` branches. However, if someone provides a complete answer to my second question too along with a good explanation to the first, I'd consider that instead. In any case, thanks!

Comment: @Kostas Edited my answer to try and explain why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @LostArrow Added an answer to your second question.

Comment: @IlCapitano Thank you very much! I feel I now have a better understanding of type deduction. The examples you provided are very good. I also think rvalue references have not completely "clicked" in my head yet. That'll hopefully get fixed with more practice. Could you explain why copying functors is not a big deal? Is it just a copy of a pointer to the actual functor?

Comment: @LostArrow Functors are structs/classes that usually have only a few members that need to be copied.  In lambdas they're usually the captured references (basically pointers), which are cheap to copy.  I suggest looking into how lambdas work under the hood, [this CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jCOwajNch0) is a good starting point.

Comment: @IlCapitano Thanks, that was a good video to improve my understanding of whatever little I know about lambdas. After a little more reading, I've arrived at the conclusion that if I capture by value in my lambda quite a few things, it might end up being slightly inefficient because of the copy (but that would be the case anyway even if I used other alternatives). However, on recursive calls to `*this.operator()(...)` i.e. `self(...)`, the same y_combinator object is being self-referenced through calls and so the `Lambda` object `lambda` is only effectively being copied once from caller in main.

Comment: @IlCapitano Is that right? If I capture by reference, the "class" that the lambda represents simply has references to original objects which are used in its body as captures. All in all, only one copy of the functor takes place in y_combinator. The efficiency of the copy of the functor depends on how I'm performing captures in the lambda. That's cool, a lot of my doubts have been cleared if that's true.